# react mobile opens with button but not a clickable component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hopefully this is pretty straightforward, but I can't seem to get anywhere.

I have a simple component where I've loaded in react-responsive-modal and created a simple modal to be opened on click.

The issue is that when I click the button element, it opens just fine. But when I click a component which calls the exact same 'open' function, it does nothing. Not even an error in the console.

How can I make this modal open when I click on the MiniCardComponent?

```
class MedJournalComponent extends React.Component {

      state = {
        open: false
      };

      onOpenModal = () => {
        this.setState({ open: true });
      };

      onCloseModal = () => {
        this.setState({ open: false });
      };

    render() {
        const { open } = this.state;
        return (
            <Column>

                <Row className={css(styles.cardsContainer)} wrap flexGrow={1} horizontal="space-between" breakpoints={{ 768: 'column' }}>
                    <Row className={css(styles.cardRow)} wrap flexGrow={1} horizontal="space-between" breakpoints={{ 384: 'column' }}>

                        <MiniCardComponent onClick={this.onOpenModal} active={this.props.selectedItem === 'Medical Journal'}  className={css(styles.miniCardContainer)} title="Medical Journal" value= <FaBookMedical /> />

                        <button onClick={this.onOpenModal}>Open modal</button>

                        <Modal open={open} onClose={this.onCloseModal}>
                          <h2>Simple centered modal</h2>
                          <p>
                            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam
                            pulvinar risus non risus hendrerit venenatis. Pellentesque sit amet
                            hendrerit risus, sed porttitor quam.
                          </p>
                        </Modal>

                    </Row>
                </Row>
            </Column>
        );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Abstract react components don't do well with event handlers.  Event handlers typically need to be attached to DOM elements.  For example, if `MiniCardComponent` looked like this:

```js
const MiniCardComponent = () => (

  <React.Fragment>
    <button>Yup</button>
    <button>Nope</button>
    <button>Perhaps</button>
  </React.Fragment>

)
```

How would React know which button which button to attach the onclick to?  You need to dig into your `MiniCardComponent` component and decive which DOM element you want the onClick to fire on.  You can then pass the onClick as a prop:

```js
const MiniCardComponent = props => (

  <div>
    <button onClick={props.onClick}>Yup</button>
    <button>Nope</button>
    <button>Perhaps</button>
  <div>

)
```

Comment: I'm confused how to apply this becaues my miniCardComponent looks like this:
```function MiniCardComponent({ className = '', title, value }) {
    const composedClassName = `${css(styles.container)} ${className}`;
    return (
        <Column flexGrow={1} className={composedClassName} horizontal="center" vertical="center">
            <span className={css(styles.title)}>{title}</span>
            <span className={css(styles.value)}>{value}</span>
        </Column>
    );
}```

Comment: Where is `<Column />` coming from?  I would say that would be the place to attach the eventhandler, but I'm not sure what that's rendering really.  If you put the `onClick` on either or both of the `<span>` elements, it will work.  You can try it on `<Column />` as well, see if it sticks.